# Find signal form in 1D Data

Tags: classification

I'm new to machine learning and was thinking about a problem I had in my data analysis. I need to detect a peak in a captured 1d signal. The peak form from the measured data can be fitted with a function which varies in maximum amplitude and width (Let's keep it simple for now). I want to detect where that peak is inside the 1d signal and if that peak follows a learned structure.

The first problem I have is to detect the peak because it is not always the highest. At the moment I use some smoothing with savitzky golay which works quite well and sharper peaks are much lower in amplitude after that.

I was thinking of training a simple feed forward network and presenting it with the 1d data but the data might be scaled depending on how the signal was measured (Time series data with different capturing length).

Is there any good literature on this topic or do you have hints for me on how to preprocess the data and extract the features?

Comment: I assume that the peak shape does not depend on the location in the time series, ie a peak in the beginning might look the same as a peak at the end or in the middle. In that case, I would suggest to use convolutional neural networks.

Comment: The signal I need to recognize may differ in location and width but I have labelled training samples where position an range is given. Depending on the settings of the scope the same peak might become larger in width but has the same shape. Are convolutional networks sensitive to different input scalings?